# How do I interpret VNP13A1: VIIRS Vegetation Indices 16-Day date?

Tags: google-earth-engine, vegetation-index, noaa, viirs

In Google Earth Engine, looking at the metadata for VNP13A1: VIIRS Vegetation Indices 16-Day 500m a start and end date is provided.

When converted to regular UTC date they are 2022-09-30 to 2022-10-08. That is 8 days apart.

Does this mean it takes into account just 8 days (not 16 as the dataset title suggests)?
Or is it 16 day breadth of imagery taken into account starting on the start date but the 8th day is the target value calculated form the best available pixels?

```
5: Image NOAA/VIIRS/001/VNP13A1/2022_09_30 (1 band)
type: Image
id: NOAA/VIIRS/001/VNP13A1/2022_09_30
version: 1666125094091188
bands: List (1 element)
properties: Object (5 properties)
system:asset_size: 15053380662
system:footprint: LinearRing, 5 vertices
system:index: 2022_09_30
system:time_end: 1665187200000
system:time_start: 1664496000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was an error at Google Earth Engine. So the period should read as 16 day length. That is from 2022-09-30 to 2022-10-16. Apparently this will be fixed soon (reported 2022-10-20).